# Cakephp adding option field with array values

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I am trying to create a drop down menu (option) and to fill this drop down i have sent an array list to the view:

```
            $country = $this->country_list;

            $this->set(compact('country'));
```

Now my question is does cake have a buildin method for me to set an input field using (`$this->Form->input()`) with the data of the array list?

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-select-checkbox-and-radio-inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take this example

```
$sizes = array(
        's' => 'Small',
        'm' => 'Medium',
        'l' => 'Large'
);

echo $this->Form->input('size', array('options' => $sizes, 'default' => 'm'));
```

Answer (score 1):

In the controller, set the value

```
$this->set('countries', $this->Country->find('list', array('fields' => 'Country.name')));
```

To show the dropdown box in the view

```
$this->Form->input('country_id');
```

Comment: this works only if he has a `Country` model and a `country_id` field but he didn't mention about it. Also: `$this->Country->find(...)` works only in CountriesController but I don't think this is the case

Comment: Worked with what was provided, he can adjust it to work within his project.

Comment: @BrianKerr Thanks for your response however the country list is not in a database and is just a plain array list?